# How to calculate age based on birthday date, problem with timestamp and datetime in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I have data frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col_date
-------
2001-01-05
1992-05-06
```

And I want to use below function to calculate age based of above column in data frame:

```
def age(born):
    """
    Desc.
    """
    born = datetime.strptime(born, '%y%m%d').date()
    date = "2021-08-01"
    return date.year - born.year - ((date.month, date.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

When I check values by `df.col_date.unique()` I have results like below:

```
array([datetime.date(2001, 1, 5), datetime.date(1992, 5, 6),dtype=object)
```

And when I use my function: `df["col_date"] = df["col_date"].apply(age)`
I have error: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date`

But When I change type from string to datetime and I use function I have error: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp` because instead of datetime I have timestamp: `'2001-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'`

What can I do I totaly do not know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try via `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
def age(born):
    """
    Desc.
    """
    born = pd.to_datetime(born,format='%Y-%m-%d')
    date = pd.to_datetime("2021-08-01")
    return date.year - born.year - (date.month<born.month and date.day<born.day)

#Finallly:
df["col_date"] = df["col_date"].apply(age)
```

OR

other way is to caculate your condition directly:

```
df['col_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['col_date'])
date = pd.to_datetime("2021-08-01")
df['col_date']=(date.year-df['col_date'].dt.year)-((df['col_date'].dt.month.lt(date.month)) & (df['col_date'].dt.day.lt(date.day)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the module `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import relativedelta

def age(born: datetime.date):
    return relativedelta.relativedelta(datetime.date.today(),born)
```

For a `datetime.date` representing 2001-01-05 this will return

```
relativedelta(years=+20, months=+7, days=+7)
```

and you can translate that as you like

```
>>> result = age(datetime.date(2001,1,5))
>>> result.years
20
>>> result.months
7
```

etc.